# Write in a field's record in an Access' table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, connection

**Issue :**

I wrote this code which is supposed to write in a specific record of the *WPRCPart* field, but for some unknown reasons, nothing happens when I run it.

There are no errors though, it's just that this execution produces no result.

The data type of the *WPRCPart* field is **Short Text**.

The data type of the *PartNo* field is **Number** and its values come from a value List in Combo Box which can contains Multiple values.

Any ideas ?

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connStr As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "mypath" & "NewVersion.accdb" & ";"
conn.ConnectionString = connStr
conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = conn
  .CommandText = "UPDATE OverViewNew Set WPRCPart = 'Yes' WHERE PartNo = 9165267"
End With

Set rs = cmd.Execute
'rs.close
```

Comment: is this true? WHERE PartNo = 9165267

Comment: yes, I mean this PartNo exists, is unique, alone in its record and PartNo's data type is Number. I tried `PartNo = '9165267'` but this returns a type mismatch error of course

Comment: Is your data on a database other than the one your VBA is running on? If not you are going a long way around to do something very simple.

Comment: No. The table `OverViewNew` is unique in this database BUT the field `WPRCPart` and `PartNo` exist in an other table from that same database. What do you suggest @SunKnight0 ?

Comment: Then you don't need any of that code. All you need is: `DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE OverViewNew Set WPRCPart = 'Yes' WHERE PartNo = 9165267"`

Comment: Hold on, are you saying that `WPRCPart` and `PartNo` are NOT fields of the `OverViewNew` table? If that is the case your SQL statement is invalid.

Comment: Oh Ok I understand what you meant now. YES this code is in a module of the database and YES those 2 fields are in the OverView Table of course. Just tried your code...it runs but there is not update of the record in question. I wonde if it is due to the fact that PartNo can contain multiple values

Comment: Oh **the issue is actually the fact that this field can contain multiple values**. Just tried `DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE OverViewNew Set WPRCPart = 'Yes' WHERE CaseNo = 8575973"` where the field _CaseNo_ is NOT a multiple values field and it works. So **an alternative** is to make this work by first retrieving the value of the _CaseNo_ field where _PartNo_ = 9165267 ( Doing this on VBA) and then do the SQl from the _CasNo_ field.